# JQuery UI Drag and Drop - add random number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop feature for a form. This all works great, but I am having issues with the dateinput using datepicker.  I essentially need to make sure each datepicker element that is dropped has a unique id.  This is an example of the drag and drop

```
$(".component").draggable({
    helper: function() {
        return $(this).clone().addClass("component-drag");
    }
}).on("click", function() {
    a.addComponent($(this));
}), 
$("#content").droppable({
    accept: ".component",
    hoverClass: "content-hover",
    drop: function(b, c) {
        a.addComponent(c.draggable)
    }   
})
```

Whatever happens, the addComponent function is called once a component has been dropped.  At the moment, this looks like the following

```
addComponent: function(a) {
    var input = a.find('input');
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    if(input.attr('id') == 'dateInput') {
        input.datepicker("destroy").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
        input.attr("id",'dateInput' + i).datepicker();
    }
    a.clone().removeClass("component").addClass("element").removeAttr("id").prepend('<div class="close">&times;</div>').appendTo("#content"), $("#options_modal").modal("hide");
},
```

So I check to see if the dragged component is a dateInput. If it is, I firstly destroy all of its original datepicker code.  I then generate a random number and add it to its id attribute.  This kind of works, but the same number is used for all dateInputs.  So if I drag two dateInput elements, they both still have the same id.

I think I need to add the id after the clone, but if I do, nothing gets applied.

How could I go about getting this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random `id` that doesn't exist along the following:

```js
var inputs = $('#content').find('[id^=["dateInput"]');
var existing = inputs.map(function(i,input) {
  return this.id.split('dateInput')[1];
}).get();

var random;
do {
  random = Math.random() * 1001; // n + 1
} while (array.indexOf(random)>=0);

// use random to generate id here
```